# Image won't display over slider (Z-index issue?)

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have an image that I want to fix over the slider (can't put it in the slides themselves as an image because it needs to stay static) but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the image to display on top of the slider image.

It seems like the plugin's parameters have it set up so the slider will be on top of the page no matter what, either that or I am missing something.

The URL for the site is: http://dev.minnesotaimed.com/

More info: The image I want to move is the one w/ 4 circles, I am hoping to put it up on the right side of the slider area.

Any help would be beyond appreciated, we're on a incredibly tight deadline and I'm getting dirty looks because I can't seem to solve this quickly. Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code for the image. This would put the below mentioned 4 circles image on the slider above. I hope it helps. Please mention in comments if there's a concern.

**CSS:**

```
img.alignright, .wp-caption.alignright {
margin: 4px 0px 2px 10px !important;
z-index: 9999999;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
}
```